# Navigation Link Hover Border-top have 2 color

Tags: css, hover, navigationbar

I'm having problem in my website that I made. When I hover the navigation link I want the `border-top` have to different color. But when I tried it many times its not working.

result when hovered  | expected result

[image]

```
<ul class="h_nav_list">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="list active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.html" class="list">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="list" class="list">ACTIVITY</a></li>
```

```
ul { padding:15px 0; }
ul li { display:inline-block; font-size:16px; padding:10px; }
ul li a { text-decoration:none; color:#222; font-weight:bold; padding-top:50px; }

ul li a.active,
ul li a:hover { color:#014880; border-top:7px solid; width:50%; }
ul li a.list:hover { border-top:7px solid #1880C9; width:50%;  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your HTML has a bug, the `href` of HOME wasn't closed with the double quote
2. The `border-top` does apply but because of the `padding-top: 50px`, it wasn't visible. I reduced it to `5px`

```css
ul {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a::before,
ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 7px;
  display: none;
}

ul li a::before {
  background: #014880;
  left: 0;
}

ul li a::after {
  background: #1880c9;
  right: 0;
}

ul li a.active,
ul li a:hover {
  color: #014880;
}

ul li a.active::before,
ul li a.active::after,
ul li a:hover::after,
ul li a.list:hover::before,
ul li a.list:hover::after {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul class="h_nav_list">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="list active">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="profile.html" class="list">PROFILE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="list" class="list">ACTIVITY</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** Apologies, misunderstood your question in the first go. Updated the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `after` `before` to achieve this, please check snippet.

```css
ul { padding:15px 0; }
ul li { display:inline-block; font-size:16px; padding:10px;position:relative; }
ul li a { text-decoration:none; color:#222; font-weight:bold; padding-top:50px; }

ul li a.active,
ul li a:hover { color:#014880; border-top:7px solid; width:50%; }
ul li a.list:hover { border-top:7px solid #1880C9; width:50%;  }

ul li a:hover:after{position:absolute; width:50%; background:#000; height:5px; content:''; left:0px; top:0px;}
ul li a:hover:before{position:absolute; width:50%; background:#ff0000; height:5px; content:''; right:0px; top:0px;}
```

```html
<ul class="h_nav_list">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="list active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.html" class="list">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="list" class="list">ACTIVITY</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo using `after` and `before`. Please check this:

```css
ul { padding:15px 0; }
.h_nav_list li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:20px 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.h_nav_list li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.h_nav_list li::before,
.h_nav_list li::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  transition: .3s all;
}
.h_nav_list li::before {
  background-color: #014880;
}
.h_nav_list li::after {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #1880C9;
}
.h_nav_list li.active::before,
.h_nav_list li.active::after,
.h_nav_list li:hover::before,
.h_nav_list li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="h_nav_list">
    <li><a href="index.html class="list active"> HOME </a </li>
    <li><a href="profile.html" class="list">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="list">ACTIVITY</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit : (See comments below..)

You can add a `linear-gradient` to your `<a>` or `<li>` element with the `border-image` property.

```css
ul li { display: inline-block; font-size: 20px; list-style: none; border-top: 4px solid darkblue; }
ul li:hover { border-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkblue 50%, aquamarine 0) 4; }
ul li a { text-decoration: none; color: black; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: *Unfortunately linear-gradient doesn't work with border.* --> they do: https://jsfiddle.net/tcnefpgo/

Comment: @TemaniAfif pretty cool indeed, didn't know the property, thanks for your comment! Will modify my post.

Answer (score -2):

try JavaScript for on mouse enter and mouse leave to add style to that element

this code for your html tag :

```
<li><a href="index.html class="list active" id="home" onmouseenter="homeEnter()" onmouseleave="homeLeave()">HOME</a></li>
```

make sure to add onload attribute to body tag , to load js function after page loaded like this :

```
<body onload="myFunction()"></body>
```

inside myFunction get documents you want to work with like this :

```
homeLink = document.getElementByID("home");
```

now you can work with your document element that named homeLink , inside your script.

to add style you want , fisrt create that class or just edit that style attribute like this :

```
homeEnter() { homeLink.style.border-top = "1px solid black" }
```

and to make sure style return to default do something like this :

```
homeLeave() { homeLink.style.border-top = '' }
```